# WSUS offline update fails due to 404

Tags: windows-update, wsus, http-status-code-404

**OS: Windows 8.1 x64**

**WSUS Offline Updater Version: 11.8 for x64**

Ok I have been trying to update my PC using WSUS offline updater, but the updater is unable to download from the URLs listed in the screenshot below.

[image]

If you query the URLs in the browser then what you get is a 404 error like the following

[image]

What can I do to mitigate this ?

**I cant update my PC using the normal update service and has Microsoft changed the update URLs ??**

**Is download.windowsupdate.com a legitimate Windows site ?**

What can I do ?

Comment: What version of wsus? What OS are you trying to update?

Comment: @Moab Added it in the question

Comment: What version of wsus?

Comment: @Moab 11.8. Added in the question.

Comment: Installed 11.8 and seems to be working just fine for me. Yes that is a valid url, wsus has been using it since its inception.

Comment: @Moab Weird. I just cant get through

Answer (score -1):

*download.windowsupdate.com*

I was able to access this URL above here. I have used WSUS Offline before myself.

Do you have unfettered Internet access?  That is, no firewall or other blockage?

Comment: This answer absolutely fails to explain the reason WSUS offline updater is unable to download the update.  The reason it’s unable to do so is clear to anyone who understands what the problem is.  This answer is unhelpful for that reason.